# Can someone spell out for me what ring isomorphisms are used in the following sequence of isomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The sequence of isomorphisms used to establish $\mathbb{Z}[i]/{\langle 1+i \rangle} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is:

\begin{align}
 \frac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{\langle 1+i \rangle} &\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\langle x^{2}+1,1+x \rangle}\\
 &\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle 1+x \rangle}{\langle x^{2}+1, 1+x \rangle/\langle 1+x \rangle}\nonumber\\
 &\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{\langle (-1)^{2}+1 \rangle}\\
 &\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\nonumber.
\end{align}

I was told that the first one uses $\mathbb{Z}[i]\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\langle x^{2}+1 \rangle}$, which seems ok but I don't understand where $1+i$ went or why it seems to have gotten replaced by $1+x$? The other isomorphism (second last) doesn't make sense either to me, and would appreciate an explanation please.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}[x]/<x^2+1>$, $x$ acts as $i$ in that it is a square root to $-1$. So, further modding out by $1+x$ is equivalent to modding out $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ by $1+i$.

Comment: In the second-to-last isomorphism, modding out by $1+x$ is equivalent to setting $x$ to $-1$. Thus, the image of $x^2+1$ mod $1+x$ is the same as $(-1)^2+1=2$ mod $1+x$. The critical point is that in $R/<f>$, the image of $f$ is $0$ and all the consequences that follow from that are applicable.

Comment: @walkar The explanation for the first isomorphism makes sense. For the other, there are multiple things being modded out and I'm still trying to make sense of your comment.

Comment: The second isomorphism is just the usual one from the Isomorphism Theorems: the one that says that if $R$ is a ring, and $I\subseteq J$ are ideals of $R$, then $J/I$ is an ideal of $R/I$ and $(R/I)/(J/I) \cong R/J$. The third comes from the "evaluation" morphism $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ given by evaluating at $1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Yes you are right, but I'm having trouble with the first and second last isomorphism. I'm sorry if I wasn't super clear. (I tried to number these in the Latex but the number is not showing for some reason.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the question in the title (explaining each isomorphism), expanding my comments.

The first isomorphism, $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 
1+i\rangle\simeq \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+1,x+1\rangle$, is secretly utilizing that $\mathbb{Z}[i]\simeq \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ via the isomorphism given by $1 \mapsto 1$ and $x \mapsto i$, extended $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly so that $1+2x \mapsto 1+2i$, for example. Then, $x+1$ and $i+1$ are the same since $x\mapsto i$.

The second isomorphism, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+1,x+1\rangle \simeq (\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x+1\rangle)/\langle x^2+1,x+1\rangle$, is using that $\langle x+1\rangle\subset \langle x^2+1,x+1\rangle$. In general, if $R$ is a ring and $I\subset J$ are ideals of $R$, then $R/J \simeq (R/I)/(J/I)$, where $J/I$ is the ideal of $R/I$ generated by the elements $r+I$ where $r \in J$. Sometimes this is called the "Third Isomorphism Theorem", the "Invert-and-Cancel Isomorphism Theorem", or the "Freshman Isomorphism Theorem".

The third isomorphism, $(\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x+1\rangle)/\langle x^2+1,x+1\rangle\simeq \mathbb{Z}/\langle (-1)^2+1\rangle$, uses that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x+1\rangle\simeq \mathbb{Z}$, via the isomorphism $1 \mapsto 1$ and $x \mapsto -1$, extended as before. (This is what I mean by "the image of $x$ is set to $-1$").

The final isomorphism is really an equality, since $(-1)^2+1=2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Use `\langle` instead of `<` and `\rangle` instead of`>`; the first are delimiters, the latter are relational symbols. That's why the spacing is sucky.